# Customize get pixel coordinate function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I ned to create a GUI wich shows an image and the user must be able to perform the following:

1 - Select several points using the mouse;

2 - When the user is done, hit "RETURN"*;

3 - After hiting "RETURN", IF the user wants to edit the one of the points, he/she must click over the desired point and drag it to where he/she wants.

I created this function:

```
function [x, y] = test(img)

[lin, col] = size(img);
fig = figure('WindowButtonDownFcn', {@func, lin, col}, 'KeyPressFcn', @keyfunc);
imshow(img, []);
% axs = axes('position', [1 col 1 lin]);
set(gca, 'Ydir', 'reverse');
x = [];
y = [];
uiwait(fig);

      function func(src, callback, lin, col)
          seltype = get(fig, 'SelectionType');
          set(gca, 'Ydir', 'reverse');
          if strcmp(seltype, 'normal')
              set(fig, 'Pointer', 'circle');
              cp = get(fig, 'CurrentPoint');
              xinit = cp(1, 1);
              yinit = cp(1, 2);
              x = [x, xinit];
              y = [y, yinit];
              hl = line('XData', xinit, 'YData', yinit, 'color', 'b', 'Marker', '.');
              set(fig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', {@moveMouse, lin, col});
              set(fig, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', @mouseRelease);
          end

          function moveMouse(src, callback, lin, col)
              cp = get(fig, 'CurrentPoint');
              xdata = [xinit, cp(1, 1)];
              ydata = [yinit, cp(1, 2)];
              set(hl, 'XData', xdata);
              set(hl, 'YData', ydata);
              drawnow;
          end

          function mouseRelease(src, callback)
              last_selection = get(fig, 'SelectionType');
              if strcmp(last_selection, 'alt')
                  set(fig, 'Pointer', 'arrow');
                  set(fig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn','');
                  set(fig, 'WindowButtonUpFcn','');
              else
                  return;
              end
          end        
      end

      function keyfunc(src, callback)
          keypressed = get(fig, 'CurrentCharacter');
          if keypressed == 13
              uiresume(fig);
          end
      end

end
```

Q1 - It can plot the image but the coordinate system has its zero at the top-left edge of the figure. *How can I move it to the left-top of the image?*

Q2 - How can I implement the item number 3 (IF the user wants to edit the one of the points, he/she must click over the desired point and drag it to where he/she wants)?

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than getting the `CurrentPoint` of the figure, you'll want to get the `CurrentPoint` of the *axes* object.

```
cp = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint');

% Then get just the x/y position
cp = cp(1,1:2);
```

For the second part of your question about dragging a point. You'll probably want to do something like the following.

1. Set the `ButtonDownFcn` for the plot object to trigger a callback function
2. Within this function find the point on the plot that is closest to the clicked point.
3. Keep track of this index and set the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` so that whenever you move the mouse, THAT point is moved to that location.
4. Set the `WindowButtonUpFcn` so that when you release the mouse button, the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` is reset.

Something like this should give you an idea.

```
set(hl, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(src,evnt)clickedLine(src))


function clickedLine(src, evnt)     
    cp = get(ancestor(src, 'axes'), 'CurrentPoint');

    xdata = get(src, 'XData');
    ydata = get(src, 'YData');

    % Find the index of the closest point
    [~, ind] = min((xdata - cp(1,1)).^2 + (ydata - cp(1,2)).^2);


    hfig = ancestor(src, 'figure');

    switch get(hfig, 'SelectionType')
        case 'alt'
            % Right click deletes a point
            xdata(ind) = [];
            ydata(ind) = [];

            set(src, 'XData', xdata, 'YData', ydata);
        otherwise
            % Set the WindowMotionFcn callback to track this point
            set(hfig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(s,e)dragPoint(src,ind), ...
                      'WindowButtonUpFcn', @(s,e)stopDrag(s));
    end
end

function dragPoint(plt, index)
    xdata = get(plt, 'xdata');
    ydata = get(plt, 'ydata');

    % Get the current point
    cp = get(ancestor(plt, 'axes'), 'CurrentPoint');

    xdata(index) = cp(1,1);
    ydata(index) = cp(1,2);

    % Update the data and refresh
    set(plt, 'XData', xdata, 'YData', ydata);

    drawnow
end

function stopDrag(hfig)
    set(hfig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', '', ...
              'WindowButtonUpFcn', '');
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one more question: Can I add a "delete" functionality? I added it, but it affects only the result (x, y vectors) but it doesn't update the line.

Comment: @Gabs Yes you can use `ind` found within the `clickedLine` to remove a specific element. Then you'll want to update the plot `xdata` and `ydata`.

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly I do that?

Comment: @Gabs I'm guessing you didn't write this code if you don't know how to do that... I have made an update to the code so that a right click on the plot deletes a point

Comment: I did write the code, but writing GUI's is definitely *not* my area... I don't really understand how the callbacks works... Sorry... :-(